# Magento 2 installing language packs (nl_NL translation)

Tags: magento, internationalization, magento2, magento-2.0

I currently have a fresh Magento 2 installation. A basicly have a store setup that is configured for the Dutch market.

I've read the Magento 2 devdocs on installating Language Packs  (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html), although the documentation seems clear, I still have some questions.

Magento 2 comes with a pre-installed Dutch Language pack, located in vendor/magento/language-nl_nl. But the language pack does not contain any translated phrases.

I created a *.csv file with the Magento console, wich collected all phrases from the vender/magento dir source files. I suppose this file is meant to be used for distribution to translaters.

After a complete translation there are several options, and I doubt wich one fitch best in my situation;

1. Create a theme and store a nl_NL.csv file insise the theme`s i18n
   dir
2. Use the Magento command line tool to pack my translated
   phrases in a Magento directory

**Option 1** seems to have a drawback, because my Dutch translations are not directly related to the current theme, but for the store with the configured nl_NL locale.

**Options 2** is unclear to me. The Magento command i18n:pack command breaks up my nl_NL.csv source file perfectly into vendor/module/i18n/nl_NL.csv files. But packing it in the vendor/magento/ dir seems not an option because of modularity problems.

Wich steps do I have to take to create a global Dutch translation that is not related with the displayed theme, is modular and can easily be distributed with amongst all my Magento 2 Projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After completing translation, you can create a "language package" under `app/i18n`. Folder naming conventions are `<vendorname>/<language_code>`. It should contain the following files
- composer.json
- language.xml
- registration.php

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2

Comment: To recap: For pre-installed language packages in the vendor/magento folder that include a composer.json and language.xml file, I still have to add the total package (language.xml ans composer.json file) to app/i18n folder?

Comment: We recommend creating your own language package. We do not recommend modifying the pre-installed language packages in vendor.

Comment: Thanks Maddy. That makes things clear. Better start translating now! ;)

Comment: I just edited my original answer, while troubleshooting [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2), we realized that vendor name needs to be in lower case, but was not documented so.

Answer (score 2):

For `i18n` You can make it like this

- Make folder named with `i18n` in `app` folder
- make sub folder same name as your theme in i18n folder

  - **EXAMPLE** `app/design/theme/custom` from this **`custom`** this is your theme name
- make language pack `folder(s)` in `i18n -> custom` folder like `en_us` or `en_gb` or `nl_nl`
- Now your folder structure will like this `app/i18n/custom/nl_nl/`

Now in this your language package folder make below files, all files will be in this folder structure `app/i18n/custom/en_us/`

**app/i18n/custom/nl_nl/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "custom/nl_nl",
    "description": "English (US) language",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**app/i18n/custom/nl_nl/language.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>nl_NL</code>
    <vendor>custom</vendor>
    <package>nl_nl</package>
</language>
```

**app/i18n/custom/nl_nl/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'custom_nl_nl',
    __DIR__
);
```

After this put your **nl_NL.csv** in your language pack folder

- `app/i18n/custom/nl_nl/nl_NL.csv`

After than run this following commands

- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Hope this will helps you