# How to install a language pack in Magento 2?

Tags: translation, magento2

I tried to follow the instructions from https://mage2.pro/t/topic/270 and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2
but I still failed.

I'm trying to change the text of the search box in the header from 'Search entire store here...' to 'Suche...'

Right now, I have the following files in app/i18n/Test/de_ch

- composer.json
- de_ch.csv
- language.xml
- registration.php

With this content in **composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "test/de_ch",
  "description": "German (Switzerland) language",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

**de_ch.csv**

```
"Search entire store here...","Suche..."
```

**language.xml**

```
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
   <code>de_CH</code>
   <vendor>Test</vendor>
   <package>de_ch</package>
</language>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,'Test_de_ch',__DIR__);
```

In the admin, I configured the store (Stores > Configuration > General > General > Locale Options > Locale) with Deutsch (Schweiz).

Then, tried to php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento cache:clean

But nothing, the text in the Search form is still 'Search entire store here...'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just tried it and got it working. You need to make few minor uppercase to lowercase changes and vice-versa.

1. Rename folder `app/i18n/Test/de_ch` to `app/i18n/test/de_ch` (lowercase t)
2. Rename file `de_ch.csv` to `de_CH.csv` (uppercase CH, this needs to be identical to the `<code></code>` in `language.xml`)
3. In `language.xml`, change `Test` to `test` (of course also add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` to the beginning of the file). This is defined in [App/Language/package.xsd](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Language/package.xsd#L36)
4. In `registration.php` too, change it to `test_de_ch`

**---- edited to add complete code ---**

In `/app/i18n/test/de_ch`
Create the following files:

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "test/de_ch",
  "description": "German (Switzerland) language",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

**de_CH.csv**

```
"Search entire store here...","Suche TESTING..."
```

**language.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_CH</code>
    <vendor>test</vendor>
    <package>de_ch</package>
</language>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'test_de_ch',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Great, it works now!
You could post the whole code to help the others :)

Comment: Yes, we updated documentation yesterday. Sorry about the capitalization errors. Please let us know if you find issues with the topic now.

Comment: Yes it works, but how is possible override it? i create app/design/Theme/default/i18n/xx_XX.csv, but it not override, so i can't add customizations if not in original csv.

Comment: @LucaS this example is for a stand alone language pack. instruction for language embedded within a theme will be different.

Comment: @Maddy i think your reply is out of scope, maybe my question is not clear. So, how is possible override stand alone language pack? I don't want change original stand alone language pack, i will lose changes when update it, so i have to extend it. Are you agree?

Comment: not work for me show error [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                     
  ku_IQ argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for list of available locales

Answer (score 2):

You can [buy it and install it](https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/cat:BuyPackage/details=1/extension=atconnect%2Fmagento-two-language-de-de) :)

`composer config repositories.atconnect composer https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz
composer require atconnect/magento-two-language-de-de`

We use this composer package structure:
magento-two-language-de-de/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "atconnect/magento-two-language-de-de",
    "description": "Magento 2.0.0: de_DE",
    "version": "2.0.0.2-stable",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

magento-two-language-de-de/language.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) AveoTrade
 Licence: https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/cat:Agreement
 */
-->
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>atconnect</vendor>
    <package>magento-two-language-de-de</package>
</language>
```

magento-two-language-de-de/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 AveoTrade
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'atconnect_magento-two-language-de-de',
    __DIR__
);
```

magento-two-language-de-de/de_DE.csv

```
"1 Hour","1 Stunde",module,Magento_AdminNotification
"12 Hours","12 Stunden",module,Magento_AdminNotification
"2 Hours","2 Stunden",module,Magento_AdminNotification
"24 Hours","24 Stunden",module,Magento_AdminNotification
"6 Hours","6 Stunden",module,Magento_AdminNotification
```

Comment: Hello Scholtz, I bought your extension, but it asks for a user and password when I "composer update". What should I provide?

Comment: Hi, already wrote you back the email, but i will reply also here.. Make sure that you have set your api key for the purchased extension, and the api key name is username and api key secret is the password. https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/cat:ApiKey

Answer (score -3):

Please try this command:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Tried it, then saw that it started with "Requested language: en_US". When finished, the translation was still not working. So I tried php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_CH. The command succeeded but I still can't see the translation.