# Magento 2.0 translation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am - as a basic magento user - trying to translate to dutch, but it is not working as expected. I've had a clean install in 2.0.

What did I do?

1. I've created a directory in app/i18n/test/nl_nl
2. I've copied the files from vendor/magento/language-nl_nl to app/i18n/test/nl_nl and changed it to:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/language-nl_nl”,
    "description": "Dutch (Netherlands) language",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Language.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>nl_NL</code>
    <vendor>magento</vendor>
    <package>nl_nl</package>
</language>
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'nl_nl',
    __DIR__
);
```

3. I've added a nl_NL.csv file
   "Search entire store here...","Zoek TESTING..."
4. Cached

And ... Nothing! Anybody willing to hint me a clue this christmas?

Thank in advance!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two error in above text:

1. magento must be test in
   language.xml
2. 'nl_nl' must be 'test_nl_nl' in Registration.php

Now it Works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what's the right way to translate strings in Magento 2, but I succeeded with the following simple approach for a German translation:

- copied `vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv` to `vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/de_DE.csv`
- opened `de_DE.csv` in a text editor and translated the values in the second column
- same approach for the several other `i18n/*.csv` files in other modules